# Getting value of dropdown menu in another component using React

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React and I am making a dropdown menu that contains different items. I want to be able to select something from the dropdown menu and then click submit on a button component I have. And then do things based on whatever was in the drop down menu.

```
class TestDropDown extends React.Component {

  state = {selectedOption: null,};
  handleChange = selectedOption => {this.setState({ selectedOption });
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    document.write(selectedOption)
    return (
        <div className="testdropdown">
          <Select value={selectedOption} onChange={this.handleChange} options={test_types}/>
        </div>);
  }
}
```

This is my dropdown menu component above. Below is my button component.

```
class ParseButton extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
      <div className='parsebutton'>
          <Button variant="primary" type='submit'>Submit</Button>{' '}
      </div>);
    }
  }
```

I am trying to figure out when I click the "Submit" button, how to read whatever was selected in the drop down and then act upon it.